# Saving a string $variable into another variable

Tags: php

first time asking here.

In php I need to insert a '$variable' as a string with the '$' sign into a $txt variable.

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `Stxt = '$your string'`?

Comment: Your answer is already in your question. Single quotes. (Also see [ask])

Comment: yeah but php thinks $your is a variable so it would insert the value of the $your variable

Comment: try adding double quotes when doing assignment:

    $txt="$variable"

Comment: With single quotes - __NO__  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

```html
  <?php $txt = '$variable' ?>
```

If you want know more how it works.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php